# Kubernetes not mounting volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have got the following daemonset.yaml file and when deploying the file I get the error

```
**Please mount it as a Docker volume before starting the container.**
```

In local, I've got a folder called keys which has two files -> `mail.private`  and `mail.txt`. I am trying to copy these files to the container using volumes and volumeMounts but I get this error

```
Cannot load the 'mail.private' file from '/etc/opendkim/domainkeys/mail.private'. Please mount it as a Docker volume before starting the container.
```

```
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: postfix
  namespace: mailserver
  labels:
    app: postfix
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postfix
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postfix
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: postfix
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet      
      containers:
      - image: <domain>/postfix:2.0        
        name: postfix
        env:
        - name: DOMAIN
          value: iogrids.com
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/opendkim/domainkeys/mail.private
          name: dkim-volume
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 2
          tcpSocket:
            port: 25
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 60
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 2
          tcpSocket:
            port: 25
          periodSeconds: 60
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "32Mi"
            cpu: "50m"
          limits:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "50m"
        ports:
        - name: smtp
          containerPort: 25
          hostPort: 25
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
            add:
            - DAC_OVERRIDE
            - FOWNER
            - SETUID
            - SETGID
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
      volumes:
      - name: dkim-volume
        hostPath:
          # directory location on host
          path: /root/keys/mail.private
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `/root/keys/mail.private` path present on your kubernetes nodes ? Does such pod start correctly ? What can you see when you `kubectl exec` into it ? Is your file mounted at `/etc/opendkim/domainkeys/mail.private` ?

Comment: The issue was to the load the file before the container starts. I've solved it using init containers. In the above case volume was getting mounted after the container has started.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a Community Wiki answer, posted for better visibility, so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

As the OP mentioned in the comments, the problem has already been solved using [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to ensure that the file is loaded before the main container starts.

The initial problem was caused by the volume getting mounted after the main container has started.